# Postprocess Depth Image to get Skeleton using the Kinect sdk / other tools?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, ros

The short question: I am wondering if the kinect SDK / Nite can be exploited to get a depth image IN, skeleton OUT software.

The long question: I am trying to dump depth,rgb,skeleton data streams captured from a v2 Kinect into rosbags. However, to the best of my knowledge, capturing the skeleton stream on Linux with ros, kinect v2 isn't possible yet. Therefore, I was wondering if I could dump rosbags containing rgb,depth streams, and then post-process these to get the skeleton stream.

I can capture all three streams on windows using the Microsoft kinect v2 SDK, but then dumping them to rosbags, with all the metadata (camera_info, sync info etc) would be painful (correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 1):

It's quite some time ago that I worked with NITE (and I only used Kinect v1) so maybe someone else can give a more up-to-date answer, but from what I remember, this should easily be possible.

As long as all relevant data is published via ROS topics, it is quite easy to record them with rosbag and play them back afterwards. Every node that can handle live data from the sensor will also be able to do the same work on recorded data coming from a bag file.

One issue you may encounter is that if you record kinect-data, the bag files are quickly becoming very large (several gigabytes). This can be problematic if you want to edit the file afterwards on a machine with very little RAM. If you only want to play the file or if you have enough RAM, this should not really be a problem, though.

Comment: The real issue here isn't if recorded streams can be played back, but whether there is a way to get skeletons out of the recorded depth. Do you mean NITE can be exploited to achieve this?

Comment: I just noticed one thing I might have understood wrong. I assumed that NITE already receives the depth images via a ROS topic. Is this the case? If not, it is probably not so easy to record and play back the depth stream.

Comment: In any case, it should be possible to pack the skeletons provided by NITE in  a custom ROS message and publish this. Then you can use rosbag to directly record the skeletons along with the depth images.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is possible to perform a NiTE2 skeleton tracking on any depth-image-stream.

Refer to: 
https://github.com/VIML/VirtualDeviceForOpenNI2/wiki/How-to-use 
and 
https://github.com/VIML/VirtualDeviceForOpenNI2/wiki/About-PrimeSense-NiTE

With this extension one can add a virtual device which allows to manipulate each pixel of the depth stream. This device can then be used for creation of a userTracker object. As long as the right device name is provided skeleton tracking can be done

> \OpenNI2\VirtualDevice\Kinect

but consider usage limits:

> NiTE only allow to been used with "Authorized Hardware"

Comment: Please add more details instead of posting reference links